# how to use resourcebundle to write arabic in java

Tags: java, arabic

may be it is foolish to ask this question but I really need to solve this problem:

I'm trying to have a code that can get Arabic strings and then display them
for Example at first it should ask you to enter your String, then in the next line it shows that word.

At first I have tried to use the code blow

```
    public class getString {          
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {  
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(System.out, true, "UTF-8");
        Reader r = new InputStreamReader(System.in, "UTF-8"); 
        char[] str ;
        str= new char[10];
        r.read(str);
        out.println(str);

}
}
```

but the output if this code is some unknown characters like

```
Ø´ÛŒØ±ÛŒÙ†
```

I have researched but unfortunately I couldn't find any thing useful except that the code blow can help me.

```
class ResourceControl extends ResourceBundle.Control {
@Override
public ResourceBundle newBundle(String baseName, Locale locale,String format, ClassLoader loader, boolean reload)
        throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException,IOException {
    String bundlename = toBundleName(baseName, locale);
    String resName = toResourceName(bundlename, "properties");
    InputStream stream = loader.getResourceAsStream(resName);
    return new PropertyResourceBundle(new InputStreamReader(stream,"UTF-8"));
}
}
```

But unfortunately the other problem is that I dont know how can I use it in my code??

can anyone please help me??
thanks for your attention in advance

Comment: Make sure that the encoding/decoding of the console is UTF-8.

Comment: yes I have checked that @Eng.Fouad :)

Comment: print it to a file and view it with an editor capable of decoding utf-8 correctly (just to see that what your are doing is basically correct).